# Errors while building the android platfom with IONIC After adding icons and splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
Running command: /home/vimal/vimal/Attendance/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/vimal/vimal/Attendance
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

  > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.436 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/vimal/vimal/Attendance/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/vimal/vimal/Attendance/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Comment: Is there any duplicate resources in android app ? Do you have 9 patch image files? lets say icon.9.png and icon.png ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a single answer to that. Some tips (possible solutions) are:

1) rename every filename who content a special character (image, html, template, javascript file, css)

2)

```
   ionic platform remove android
   ionic platform add android
```

3) check in  /resources/android/splash folder to see for broken images

4)

```
   ionic platform remove android
   ionic platform add android
   ionic state restore
   ionic resources
```